# golang update elasticsearch with painless query

Tags: go, elasticsearch

In my go project I need to execute a query to update an elasticsearch document.  I am trying to execute a painless query to execute the update, but cannot find any documentation or example of how to use the update function.  I am using

`github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8`

All the examples I searched seem to be using an older version of the library.  The one/version I am using has the following syntax for update

`type Update func(index string, id string, body io.Reader, o ...func(*UpdateRequest)) (*Response, error)`

I am not sure what to give for the `body` and what its purpose is ?

Comment: When you say, "update", do you simply mean replace the document with a newer version? Because if you just want to reindex a document, don't use the update API, simply use Index.

Comment: actually I want to update one of the fields.

Comment: In fact, there's no way to update a single field - you need to reindex the whole document. The update API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update.html) lets you use a script to do the update, but I suspect you don't need that fancy-ness. Unless of course you are aware of this and have good reasons to be scripting the updates.

Comment: BTW, the body is an IO reader from which the update script is read.

Comment: thanks, I saw that, however I'm not sure about the last `o` function, it seems to take the correct parameters for a painless request.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/master/esapi/api.update.go
You'll see that o is a slice of functions defined by you, each of which gets called on the UpdateRequest.

Comment: Found a working sample and it worked: https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/issues/76